# Meaning of "To Lase"

Tags: meaning, verbs, terminology

There is a verb that I am unable to translate with google translator .. It is "To lase" .. For the context, I found it in this phrase:
"In these special cases if You have no suitable power meter You are just unable to make Your laser to lase"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laser (or LASER) is an acronym (initials pronounced as a word) of "Light Amplification by Stimulated Emission of Radiation".

It resembles, but is not, a noun for a person or thing that does an action, of the type formed by the action verb followed by 'er' (e.g. heater, killer, banker, burner, etc).

People, especially those working with laser equipment, find it convenient in casual conversation to pretend it is such a noun, and back-form a verb 'to lase', meaning 'to produce laser (or coherent) light'.

If you have a laser and you say that it 'lases' you mean that it functions (or functions correctly).

[Laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser)